# Java interface freezing while using thread

Tags: java, multithreading, interface

i am using the following code, i am trying to insert a new user into a database

```
if(!userText.getText().equals("") && !passwordText.getText().equals(""))
        {
        try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Poo";
        String user="root";
        String pass="";
        Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        System.out.println("connected");
        Statement st=cn.createStatement();



                    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select ID,Name,Password from Users");

                    while(rs.next()){

        if (userText.getText().equals(rs.getString("Name"))
                           && passwordText.getText().equals(rs.getString("Password")))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Correct");

                                user=rs.getString("Name");
                                id=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("ID"));

                                l2.setForeground(Color.green);
                                l2.setText("Authentication Successful"); 

                                Thread.sleep(2500);
                                break;
                            }
                    else{
                                l2.setForeground(Color.red);
                                l2.setText("Wrong Username or Password!");
                            }

                            } 


        }catch(Exception f){System.out.println(f.getMessage());}
        System.out.println(userText.getText()+" " +passwordText.getText());
    }
```

on the execution the interface in freezing and i can't see the "Successful" for the 2500 ms, any thoughts ?

Comment: FYI Java is not spelled JAVA.

Comment: Are you doing this on the GUI thread?

Comment: What is the output of your console?

Comment: Your title says *while using thread*. You're not using any thread here. Also, why do you load ALL the users from the database to find the one with the given username and password? Why don't you use a where clause on the query, to load JUST the user you're looking for? Besides, why do you sleep for 2.5 seconds? That will of course prevent the thread to do anything, and thus freeze the GUI.

Comment: I don't see any background threading type code, so we have to assume that you are in fact doing all this on the Swing event dispatch thread  or EDT, the single thread responsible for Swing user interaction and GUI drawing. If you tie up this thread, you freeze your GUI. The solution is to do most of this code in a background thread such as in a SwingWorker's `doInBackground()` method. Just be sure to make no Swing calls, other than `repaint()` if needed, from within the background thread.

Comment: @screenmutt "correct", the query was successful

Comment: Please read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to see how to use a SwingWorker.